# How to remount as read-write a specific mount of device?

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, embedded, busybox

How to remount as **read-write** a specific mount of device? (one folder) The file is "Read-only file system", rw-r-r, so it not allow to change permissions. I need to replace that file, then change permissions back to read-only.
I know command

```
mount -o rw,remount [destination folder]
```

I know this method is unstable, and may cause complications (every mount will get changed). So I must be sure that this will remount as read-write only a `specific destination folder`, not every mount of the device. I need do this on running system, not test environment. Embedded linux system. Is that possible?

Path to folder: `/etc/foo/bar` I need remount `/bar` folder.

EDIT:

```
mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on / type squashfs (ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
ramfs on /var type ramfs (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw)
/dev/mtdblock4 on /nvram type jffs2 (rw)
```

output of cat /proc/mounts

```
cat /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / squashfs ro 0 0
proc /proc proc rw 0 0
ramfs /var ramfs rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw 0 0
/dev/mtdblock4 /nvram jffs2 rw 0 0
```

remount command

```
<root@elocal:/etc/foo/bar> ls -la
total 6
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     0               98 Jan 18  2011 .
drwxrwxr-x    7 root     0              105 Feb 10  2011 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0             1052 Jan 18  2011 file1
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0              270 Jan 18  2011 file2
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0             1088 Jan 18  2011 file3
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0              270 Jan 18  2011 file4

mount -o rw,remount /etc/foo/bar
mount: can't find /etc/foo/bar in /proc/mounts
```

Comment: You might be able to do so by editing the `/etc/fstab` config file. I will see if there is a specific way of doing so.

Comment: You can't mount only a folder from a filesystem, unless you're talking about a bind mount. Also what's exactly wrong with `mount -o rw,remount`?

Comment: Do you actually mean a specific **mount** (with multiple bind mounts, which you don't have right now on your setup), or a specific **directory tree**? What kernel version do you have? The support for differing options on different bind mounts has changed over time (see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128336/why-doesnt-mount-respect-the-read-only-option-for-bind-mounts, especially the comments).

Answer (score 1):

No; you can not apply mount flags to directories, only the whole filesystem, so you have to make the whole thing rw.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of editing the `/etc/fstab` config file so that you can create a bind mount:

`/my/real/dir /to/mount/dir <filesystem> rw,bind 0 0`

- none - No options associated with mount point (like quotas)
- rw - The mount point is read and writeable.
- bind - The mount point is a bound
- directory filesystem - ext2,ext3,vfat,etc.

Comment: Yes, but if `/my/real/dir` is read-only, this won't create a read-write view. Debian used to have a patch for that but [since 3.3, this no longer works](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128336/why-doesnt-mount-respect-the-read-only-option-for-bind-mounts).

Answer (score 0):

```
mount -o rw,remount /foo
```

will remount `/foo` mount point rw. If there is a `/foo/bar` mount point (whether `ro` or `rw`), the mount command will likely fail.

If there are `/foo/what` and /foo/ever directories, those will be `rw` as well.
If your read-only mount point is

```
/foo
/bar
/baz
```

then

```
mount -o rw,remount /foo
```

will keep other mount points read only.

Comment: "If there is a `/foo/bar` mount point (whether `ro` or `rw`), the mount command will likely fail." If I understand what you are saying correctly, I don't think this is true.

Comment: Path to folder: `/etc/foo/bar` I need remount `/bar` folder. Should I use `mount -o rw,remount /etc`?

Comment: @triwo Are you sure you aren't saying “mount” when you mean “directory”?

Comment: I'm closing my question. I can't find helpful info on resolving this issue.